# transforming XML with XSL

Tags: php, xml, xslt

As the title says, I'm trying to transform an XML file using XSL at the server. My XML file saves to the server and displays fine. However if I try transforming it, nothing displays. Here is the code in question.

**XML.PHP**

```
<?php 
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");//Tell browser to expect xml
include ("config/init.php"); 
$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName) or die("you did not connect");
$query = "SELECT * FROM art";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
//Top of xml file
$_xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; 
$_xml .="<art>"; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
$_xml .="<art>"; 
$_xml .="<art_name>".$row['name']."</art_name>"; 
$_xml .="<art_category>".$row['category']."</art_category>"; 
$_xml .="<art_price>".$row['price']."</art_price>"; 
$_xml .="</art>"; 
} 
$_xml .="</art>"; 
//Parse and create an xml object using the string
$xmlobj=new SimpleXMLElement($_xml);
//And output
//print $xmlobj->asXML();
//or we could write to a file
$xmlobj->asXML('art.xml');
?>
```

**XSL.PHP**

```
<?php require 'header.php';?>
<div class="sixteen columns">
<?php 
//Create a DomDocument object

  $xml = new DOMDocument;

  // Load the XML source

  $xml -> load('art.xml');


//Similar with XSL

  $xsl = new DOMDocument;

  $xsl -> load('art.xsl');

  // Create and Configure the transformer

  $proc = new XSLTProcessor;

  // attach the xsl rules

  $proc -> importStyleSheet($xsl);

  //Output

  echo $proc -> transformToXML($xml);


?>
</div>
<?php require 'footer.php'; ?>
```

EDIT

aplogies about the late reply. When saved, the XML file now holds data. Here is are the files as requested.

**art.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<art><art><art_name>Game Weapons</art_name><art_category>Weapons</art_category><art_price>11</art_price></art><art><art_name>Violet</art_name><art_category>Scenery</art_category><art_price>11</art_price></art><art><art_name>Wolf</art_name><art_category>Character</art_category><art_price>11</art_price></art><art><art_name>A Calvert</art_name><art_category>Character</art_category><art_price>11</art_price></art><art><art_name>Scatter Character</art_name><art_category>Character</art_category><art_price>11</art_price></art><art><art_name>Bonfire</art_name><art_category>Scenery</art_category><art_price>11</art_price></art><art><art_name>Clouds</art_name><art_category>Scenery</art_category><art_price>11</art_price></art><art><art_name>Dawn</art_name><art_category>Scenery</art_category><art_price>11</art_price></art><art><art_name>Face</art_name><art_category>Character</art_category><art_price>11</art_price></art><art><art_name>Scarra</art_name><art_category>Character</art_category><art_price>11</art_price></art><art><art_name>Scatter World</art_name><art_category>Scenery</art_category><art_price>11</art_price></art><art><art_name>Woods</art_name><art_category>Scenery</art_category><art_price>11</art_price></art><art><art_name>f</art_name><art_category>f</art_category><art_price>2</art_price></art></art>
```

**art.xsl**

```
<!--  Edited with XML Spy v4.2  -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>Art</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#333">
<th align="left" style="padding:0 0 0 20px;"><font color="#FFF">Name</font></th>
<th align="left" style="padding:0 0 0 15px;"><font color="#FFF">Category</font></th>
<th align="left" style="padding:0 0 0 5px;"><font color="#FFF">Price</font></th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="art/art">
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">
<xsl:value-of select="art_name"/>
</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">
<xsl:value-of select="art_category"/>
</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">
<xsl:value-of select="art_price"/>
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT**

Turns out there was noting wrong with the code. The server has XSL disabled....working now. Thanks for the help

Comment: How does the XML look, how the XSLT? Which output do you want, which one do you get?

Comment: i have two pages, XML.php just displays it raw fine. But the XSL.php displays nothing at all

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Please show what `art.xml` and `art.xsl` look like.

Comment: @MathiasMüller edited to show them. Sorry about the late reply

Comment: @AndersNK Please do not "improve" OP's code.

Comment: Why does your XSLT output a complete HTML document if your PHP puts the transformation result into a `div` element?

Comment: @michael.hor257k what's wrong with formatting it to be more readable?

Comment: What happens if you use `<xsl:output method="html" version="4.01" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>` instead of the odd `version="1.0"` your code has?

Comment: @MartinHonnen nothing, the same

Comment: @AndersNK "*what's wrong with formatting it to be more readable?*" Perhaps nothing, perhaps everything. We won't know that until the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've saved the content of the `art.xml` in a file called just that, and saved the content of your transformation in another file called `arttrans.xsl` in the same locaion.

Then running this very simple script in PHP

```
<h1>something</h1>
<?php   
    $xml = new DOMDocument;
    $xml->load('art.xml');

    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load('arttrans.xsl');

    // Configure the transformer
    $proc = new XSLTProcessor;
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules

    echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
?>
```

gives the following result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<h2>Art</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#333">
<th align="left" style="padding:0 0 0 20px;"><font color="#FFF">Name</font></th>
<th align="left" style="padding:0 0 0 15px;"><font color="#FFF">Category</font></th>
<th align="left" style="padding:0 0 0 5px;"><font color="#FFF">Price</font></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">Game Weapons</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">Weapons</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">Violet</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">Scenery</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">Wolf</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">Character</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">A Calvert</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">Character</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">Scatter Character</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">Character</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">Bonfire</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">Scenery</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">Clouds</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">Scenery</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">Dawn</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">Scenery</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">Face</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">Character</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">Scarra</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">Character</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">Scatter World</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">Scenery</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">Woods</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">Scenery</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 0;">f</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">f</td>
<td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;">2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

I've generated this result using PHP running in Apache in XAMPP. The transformation looks fine, so maybe the issue lies with the input.

EDIT: I've inserted a headline. This headline is printed whether the transformation is run or not - just to be absolutely sure you are targetting the right webpage.

Comment: @AndresNK what you do you mean by the input?

Comment: The input to the transformation - are you absolutely sure you are running the transformation on the provided XML data, and not something else? Because when I run the transformation on `art.xml`, I obtain the result above

Comment: @AndresNK I've just done as you have, copied both art.xml and art.xsl contents to new files and uploaded them to the server. I've then used your php script but with no luck. Still the same problem. Displaying nothing

Comment: I've updated the answer with a heading in the script. Just to be absolutely sure you are hitting the right website.